# Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb"

Tags: qt

I was running a code from yolact which requires cv2 qt. I encounter the following error.

> qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in
> "/home/zhengjie/anaconda3/envs/yolact-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cv2/qt/plugins"
> even though it was found. This application failed to start because no
> Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application
> may fix this problem.
>
> Available platform plugins are: xcb, eglfs, linuxfb, minimal,
> minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, wayland-egl, wayland,
> wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx, webgl.

Within the directory of

> /home/zhengjie/anaconda3/envs/yolact-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cv2/qt/plugins

I find the file: `libqxcb.so` I have tried re-installing qt but it does not work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you found any solutions? I am having a similar problem...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [QT6: "qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68036484/qt6-qt-qpa-plugin-could-not-load-the-qt-platform-plugin-xcb-in-even-thou)

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem.My opencv-python version is 4.5.3.56,in Linux.Then i reinstall opencv-python.

```py
pip intsall opencv-python==4.3.0.36
```