# "qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found."

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, qt6

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 via Oracle VM Virtual Box and I faced exactly the same error as all other people.

After building Qt6 source code using official Qt manual, I'm trying to run different projects to test if everything works properly. Console-type projects build and run properly. There are no errors. Unfortunately, when I try to run a widget-type application, it fails with the well-known error:

```
t.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, xcb.
```

My colleague, who has Qt6 working properly on his Ubuntu, saw that I don't have `libqxcb.so` in the `.../qtbase/plugins/platforms`, and shared it with me.

Unfortunately, it didn't help much. Only the error message has changed a bit: it says that plugin was found, but couldn't be used.

The below command had no impact:

```
sudo apt install libxcb-icccm4 libxcb-image0 libxcb-keysyms1 libxcb-render-util0
```

Also, there's more verbose output with environmental variable `QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1`:

```
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/home/curiouspan/qt6-build/qtbase/plugins/platforms" ...
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/curiouspan/qt6-build/qtbase/plugins/platforms/libqeglfs.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/curiouspan/qt6-build/qtbase/plugins/platforms/libqeglfs.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "eglfs"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 1,
    "className": "QEglFSIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": true,
    "version": 393728
}


Got keys from plugin meta data QList("eglfs")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/curiouspan/qt6-build/qtbase/plugins/platforms/libqlinuxfb.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/curiouspan/qt6-build/qtbase/plugins/platforms/libqlinuxfb.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "linuxfb"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 1,
    "className": "QLinuxFbIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": true,
    "version": 393728
}


Got keys from plugin meta data QList("linuxfb")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/curiouspan/qt6-build/qtbase/plugins/platforms/libqminimal.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/curiouspan/qt6-build/qtbase/plugins/platforms/libqminimal.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "minimal"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 1,
    "className": "QMinimalIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": true,
    "version": 393728
}


Got keys from plugin meta data QList("minimal")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/curiouspan/qt6-build/qtbase/plugins/platforms/libqminimalegl.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/curiouspan/qt6-build/qtbase/plugins/platforms/libqminimalegl.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "minimalegl"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 1,
    "className": "QMinimalEglIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": true,
    "version": 393728
}


Got keys from plugin meta data QList("minimalegl")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/curiouspan/qt6-build/qtbase/plugins/platforms/libqoffscreen.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/curiouspan/qt6-build/qtbase/plugins/platforms/libqoffscreen.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "offscreen"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 1,
    "className": "QOffscreenIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": true,
    "version": 393728
}


Got keys from plugin meta data QList("offscreen")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/curiouspan/qt6-build/qtbase/plugins/platforms/libqvnc.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/curiouspan/qt6-build/qtbase/plugins/platforms/libqvnc.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "vnc"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 1,
    "className": "QVncIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": true,
    "version": 393728
}


Got keys from plugin meta data QList("vnc")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/curiouspan/qt6-build/qtbase/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/curiouspan/qt6-build/qtbase/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "xcb"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QXcbIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 393728
}


Got keys from plugin meta data QList("xcb")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/home/curiouspan/QtTestProjects/build-WidgetTestApp-Own_Desktop-Debug/platforms" ...
Cannot load library /home/curiouspan/qt6-build/qtbase/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so: (libQt6XcbQpa.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
QLibraryPrivate::loadPlugin failed on "/home/curiouspan/qt6-build/qtbase/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so" : "Cannot load library /home/curiouspan/qt6-build/qtbase/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so: (libQt6XcbQpa.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)"
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, xcb.
```

It shows that `libQt6XcbQpa.so.6` file is missing.

After running `ldd /home/curiouspan/qt6-build/qtbase/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so` to show the dependencies, I got the following output:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fffc8770000)
    libQt6XcbQpa.so.6 => not found
    libQt6Gui.so.6 => /home/curiouspan/qt6-build/qtbase/plugins/platforms/../../lib/libQt6Gui.so.6 (0x00007f0873306000)
    libQt6Core.so.6 => /home/curiouspan/qt6-build/qtbase/plugins/platforms/../../lib/libQt6Core.so.6 (0x00007f087295d000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f087277c000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f087258a000)
    libEGL.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libEGL.so.1 (0x00007f0872573000)
    libX11.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007f0872436000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f0872430000)
    libQt6DBus.so.6 => /home/curiouspan/qt6-build/qtbase/plugins/platforms/../../lib/libQt6DBus.so.6 (0x00007f0872262000)
    libGLX.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX.so.0 (0x00007f087222e000)
    libOpenGL.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOpenGL.so.0 (0x00007f0872202000)
```

So this file is really missing. What can be the potential problem, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 59):

For the Qt 6.5.0 release, the missing library was `libxcb-cursor.so.0`, resolved with

```
sudo apt install libxcb-cursor0
```

With that, the sample widget and gui projects from QtCreator run correctly built with Qt 6.5.0.  libxcb-cursor.so.0 wasn't previously needed for Qt 6.4.0.

I identified the missing library with this shell code

```
for l in /path/to/Qt/6.5.0/gcc_64/lib/*.so; do
  echo $l; objdump -p $l | grep NEEDED | sed "s/^/\t"/;
 done | grep xcb | awk '{print $2}' \
| while read lib; do echo $lib; dlocate $lib; done
```

This scans all the install Qt libraries, extracts their required dependency libraries related to xcb, then prints which debian package provides each libxcb* library.  On my system it reported a debian package for each libxcb*.so library except libxcb-cursor.so.0

Comment: My original solution used `for l in $(cat)` to loop over and inspect the xcb libs. It's probably better to use `while read lib` since `$(cat)` might not work cleanly, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/29560278/12401525

Answer (score 19):

I solved this problem by running this command in console

```
sudo apt install libxcb-xinerama0
```

The original link [here](https://discuss.pixls.us/t/solved-could-not-load-the-qt-platform-plugin-xcb-in-even-though-it-was-found/17677/3)

Answer (score 19):

One of the easiest approaches which helped me,type this in console:

```
export QT_QPA_PLATFORM=offscreen
```

More you can read [here](https://github.com/NVlabs/instant-ngp/discussions/300). I hope it would help you!

Comment: I tried to implement this on my Dockerfile and got a new error `WebEngineContext is used before QtWebEngineQuick::initialize() or OpenGL context creation failed.
[1:1:0922/214114.391383:ERROR:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(100)] Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported. See https://crbug.com/638180.
"/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/PySide6/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqoffscreen.so" unloaded library`

Comment: @Adam, Thank you for letting me know. Actually, I didn't use this on the Dockerfile but now I know that it won't work in that way, thanks

Comment: what ended up working for me was a combination of your suggestion and one more line, so I had to have both `ENV QT_QPA_PLATFORM=offscreen` and `ENV QTWEBENGINE_DISABLE_SANDBOX=1`. Thanks for getting me halfway there!

Comment: QT_QPA_PLATFORM=offscreen works, but now my app does not appear on the screen at all.

Answer (score 7):

I solved this problem by installing PyQt5 dependences

```
sudo apt-get install '^libxcb.*-dev' libx11-xcb-dev libglu1-mesa-dev libxrender-dev libxi-dev libxkbcommon-dev libxkbcommon-x11-dev
```

Answer (score 5):

If you're on `Centos`, this solved the problem for me:

```
sudo yum install xcb-util*
```

Answer (score 4):

For me
`pip install pyqt6` worked.

My application was running on matplotlib and needed an external GUI. So, I tried to install TK, it didn't worked. On installing pyqt5, it gave me the same error as yours, so I remove it. PyQT6 though worked perfectly. I had also installed libxcb (`sudo yum install libxcb`), but xcb plugin should not be needed in wayland env.

Answer (score 2):

I got this same message for a completely different reason. I had had to recreate a python virtual env from scratch after it wouldn't install `tensorflow-gpu` due to package inconsistencies. That environment had for many months been working correctly with qt, and I had all the qt `lib*.so` dependencies correctly installed. My rebuilt environment did now have `tensorflow-gpu` and no package inconsistencies according to conda, but my program was broken now at runtime with this Qt platform plugin xcb error. It turned out that while rebuilding the env i had installed `opencv-python` via pip, which installed some various Qt packages specific to opencv and python.  But, if I installed `qt` via conda, before installing `opencv-python` via pip, then pip did not subsequently install those Qt packages for `opencv-python`, and the xcb plugin error was now fixed.

Comment: `opencv-python` was indeed the culprit for me.  As soon as I installed it, I started facing the error from OP.
Unfortunately, first installing `pyqt` through conda, and only after that installing `opencv-python` through pip, did not solve the issue for me.
What solved the issue is:
1) first install pyqt through conda
2) now do `conda install -c conda-forge opencv`
3) finally: `pip install opencv-python`

Answer (score 2):

you can try delete pyqt5. I have successed using this method.

pip uninstall PyQt5

Answer (score 1):

After a fresh installation of Qt Creator, I met the same issue.

I solved it by installing `libxcb-xinerama0`.

```
sudo apt install libxcb-xinerama0
```

Answer (score 1):

On **Rocky Linux 8.6**, this solution also works. Thanks [@Ivan Sivak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2717169/ivan-sivak)

```
sudo dnf install xcb-util*
```

Answer (score 1):

`opencv-python` now uses Qt6 (at least at version 4.7.0.72). Installing Qt6 solved it for me

```bash
sudo apt install qt6-base-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm working with Linux Mint 21 and using VSCode as my editor. I was just trying to run a simple GUI application when I encountered an issue. I have installed Pyenv and was able to resolve the problem by running the following command:
`sudo apt install '^libxcb.*-dev' libx11-xcb-dev libglu1-mesa-dev libxrender-dev libxi-dev libxkbcommon-dev libxkbcommon-x11-dev` 
This command installs several development libraries and dependencies that are required by some Python packages. By running this command, I was able to fix the issue I was facing.

Answer (score 1):

As for me, the `platforms` directory is absent from the directory `qrelease`. Just copy it from the `Qt` installing directory and the error will be gone.

Answer (score 1):

My solution to this was to set the appropriate `DISPLAY` variable. Specifically, `export DISPLAY=0.0` fixed the issue. The issue disappeared after that, curiously...

Answer (score 1):

I'm using opencv with PyQt5, and this did work for me:

```
pip uninstall opencv-python opencv-contrib-python opencv-python-headless
pip install opencv-python-headless
```

Answer (score 0):

For me this error was due to a mismatch between python PyQt5 and Ubuntu QT6, which I solved via:

```
pip uninstall pyqt5
sudo apt install qt6-base-dev
pip install pyqt6
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use SSH to remotely operate the Linux server and run the GUI program, this may be an environmental variable problem.Run your program with sudo -E instead of sudo,it will retain your environment variables and increase permissions at the same time. Maybe you need to execute twice.

```
 sudo -E /path/to/your/program
```

Suggest using MobaXterm, which provides GUI callback support.

Answer (score 0):

I was using OpenCV in a Python virtual environment in WSL. For me, this error was fixed after running this command.

```
sudo apt install xcb
```

Answer (score 0):

first, `echo $QT_QPA_PLATFORM`, to see if it is `xcb`
second, locate where the `qt plugins` is,
such as  `/anaconda3/envs/envsam/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cv2/qt/plugins/platforms`
`ls`,
then we `rm libqxcb.so`
which will solve the problem.Hope this will work for you all!

Answer (score 0):

```
export QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland
```

Adding the above export assignment works on Wayland in Ubuntu Mantic OS.

Answer (score -2):

```
export QT_QPA_PLATFORM=offscreen
```

This fixed, as it is written in the [link](https://github.com/NVlabs/instant-ngp/discussions/300) provided by OP.

Comment: Why did you copy an already existing post?