# Spyder WSL : Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found

Tags: qt, ubuntu, spyder, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I recently tried to install spyder on a WSL (Ubuntu 22.04 LTS) on windows 11.

[And when I tried to open "spyder", I obtain this error message:

could not connect to display :0
Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, wayland-egl, wayland, wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx, webgl, xcb.

Aborted]

If someone can help me ?

Answer (score 1):

This question is essentially the same as [QT6: "qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68036484/qt6-qt-qpa-plugin-could-not-load-the-qt-platform-plugin-xcb-in-even-thou)

You need to give more detail, are you trying to access Qt from the debian packages built for Ubuntu, or did you install Qt using the qt.io installer?  The ubuntu packages should have been built declaring all required packages (if they haven't then that's a packaging bug).

My guess is you've used the qt.io installer.  It doesn't know which ubuntu packages have been installed.  You find this xcb error when the required libxcb* packages are not installed.

This question is only 3 days old, the same timeframe as the new Qt 6.5.0 release.  Qt 6.5.0 introduced a new dependency, libxcb-cursor0. You might fix that with

```
sudo apt install libxcb-cursor0
```

See more discussion at https://stackoverflow.com/a/75941575/12401525