# QT - plugin xcb can't be loaded

Tags: linux, qt

I am trying to run an application using QT but I am getting the following error

```
qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display 
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, wayland-egl, wayland, wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx, xcb.

08:44:28: The program has unexpectedly finished.
```

My OS is Rocky 8.8.
Any idea what may be the cause of this error and how can I fix it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [QT6: "qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68036484/qt6-qt-qpa-plugin-could-not-load-the-qt-platform-plugin-xcb-in-even-thou)